# facebook android sdk - Only developer account can share posts but other users can't

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I'm trying to share a link in the user feed through the below code and it will work only I log in using the developer account. If I try to post it through any other user account it will only give a post ID but there is no visible post.

MainFragment contains only the layout inflater which this layout has only a TextView and facebook LoginButton

```
package com.chamika.fbtest;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.FacebookRequestError;
import com.facebook.HttpMethod;
import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.RequestAsyncTask;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionDefaultAudience;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    private Context context;

    private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";

    private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions","publish_stream");
    private static final int REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE = 100;

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    private MainFragment mainFragment;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
            mainFragment = new MainFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment).commit();
        } else {
            // Or set the fragment from restored state info
            mainFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
        // resultCode, data);
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
            text.setText("Logged in...");
            text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    publish();
                }
            });

        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
            text.setText("Logged out...");
            text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    text.setText("Please log");
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void publish() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        if (session == null || !session.isOpened()) {
            return;
        }

        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
        if (!permissions.containsAll(PERMISSIONS)) {
            requestPublishPermissions(session);
            return;
        }

        // Show a progress dialog because sometimes the requests can take a
        // while.
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "requesting permission",
                "requesting additional permission", true);

        Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
        postParams.putString("name", "Test post");
        postParams.putString("caption", "This is a test post");
        postParams.putString("description",
                "Description of the test post");
        postParams.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
        postParams.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

        Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
                String postId = null;
                try {
                    postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                    Log.d(TAG, "postId=" + postId);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "JSON error " + e.getMessage());
                }
                FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                if (error != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), error.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), postId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        };

        Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, callback);

        RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
        task.execute();

    }

    private void requestPublishPermissions(Session session) {
        if (session != null) {
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS)
            // demonstrate how to set an audience for the publish permissions,
            // if none are set, this defaults to FRIENDS
                    .setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS).setRequestCode(REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE);
            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
        // session is not null, the session state change notification
        // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
        // Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        // if (session != null && (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed())) {
        // onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
        // }
        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**By default app is in Sandbox Mode(only visible to Admins,Developers and Testers)**

[image]

**Disable sandbox mode.(To visible all users)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you might have forgotten to add the tester privileges to the facebook accounts that you tried other than the developer account. As you are developing your app it will be in Sandbox mode in which only developer account and tester accounts will be having access.Go to your apps in developer.facebook.com and add tester accounts.

Comment: Thank you for responding. But I've done a mistake by giving privacy as "Only Me" for my test profile. If I access the profile I can see all the wall post.

Your answer is valid for a facebook app which enables sandbox. In my case I've disabled it

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the Explicit Sharing parameter (`fb:explicitly_shared`).

As said on [this page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/explicit-sharing/):  "Explicitly shared actions are eligible to appear as stand-alone stories in the news feed".
This thing applies to the Open Graph specification, but I think that is valid also in your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("name", "Your App Name or any desired name");
    params.putString("description", "Message to share");
    params.putString("picture", "Image Url");

    WebDialog feedDialog = (
        new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(context,
            Session.getActiveSession(),
            params))
        .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                FacebookException error) {
                if (error == null) {
                    // When the story is posted, echo the success
                    // and the post Id.
                    final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                    if (postId != null) {
                        FacebookHelper.this.mShareDelegate
                        .shareStatus();
                    } else {
                        // User clicked the Cancel button

                    }
                } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                    // User clicked the "x" button

                } else {
                    // Generic, ex: network error

                }
            }

        })
        .build();
    feedDialog.show();
```